# Solution for Argument list too long

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

I have the below shell script which reads a file, copies the content of the file to a variable and passes the variable as argument to another command.

```
declare -a arr=()
while IFS= read -r var
do
  arr+=( $var )
done < "accounts.json"
args=''
for j in "${arr[@]}"
 do
   args="$args $j"
 done
 peer chaincode invoke -n cc -C channel1 -c '{"Args":["InitLedgerAdvanced",'"\"$args\""']}'
```

This works very well when the accounts.json file is small. But I get an error that says "Argument list too long" when the size of accounts.json is too large. I have tried xargs but to no success.

edit 1:

below is example json file with only two rows

```
[{"accountID":"C682227132","accountStatus":"1"},
{"accountID":"C800427392","accountStatus":"1"}]
```

Below is what a peer command would look like with actual data

```
peer chaincode invoke -n cc -C channel1 -c '{"Args":["InitLedgerAdvanced","[{"accountID":"C682227132","accountStatus":"1"},
{"accountID":"C800427392","accountStatus":"1"}]"]}'
```

Comment: You would not be able to use `xargs` here as you (I assume) you need to give the complete JSON document in one go.  Is that correct? Can that `peer` command be made to read the document from a file instead from the command line? (Note: I'm unsure what `peer` is).

Comment: Yes, I need the complete json document in one go. I cannot use the peer command to read document from a file. peer is not a native unix/linux command. It comes from Hyperledger fabric (a blockchain service).

Comment: Please show a sample of the input file and show what the `-c` argument is supposed to look like. I bet a simple [tag:jq] script is all that's required. That would mean you don't need to break up the file into lines and then combine the lines into a string: jq would do that for you.

Comment: @glennjackman That wouldn't make the actual argument to `peer` shorter in the end, would it?

Comment: @glennjackman. I have edited my question and added a few examples. Please don't worry about use of double quotes inside single quotes. I have made sure to have escape characters

Comment: @Kusalananda, is there a "command length too long" that's distinct from "argument list too long"??

Comment: @user344247, don't you need to escape the inner quotes ? `-c '{"Args":["InitLedgerAdvanced","[{\"accountID\":\"C682227132\",...`

Comment: @glennjackman. Yes. I do need these inner quotes. I deliberately did not mention them here to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *might* work

```
# slurp the accounts file into a variable
accounts=$(< accounts.json)

# create the json, escaping the accounts quotes along the way
printf -v json '{"Args":["InitLedgerAdvanced","%s"]}' "${accounts//\"/\\\"}"

# and invoke the command
peer chaincode invoke -n cc -C channel1 -c "$json"
```

If that still gives you trouble, you'll have to find a way to pass the `-c` argument to "peer" via stdin or a file, not as a command line argument.